# At least 3 letters for all languages with whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which recognize at least 3 letters from whole string for all languages.

I tried

```
/\p{L}{3}/u
```

But its not working for name `Wu ko`

I need something like this:

| test string | expected result |
| --- | --- |
| `t me` | true |
| `wu ko` | true |
| `Ker le` | true |
| `john doe` | true |
| `f i` | false |
| `fe` | false |

Comment: Use `const regex = /(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){3}/u` or `const regex = /^(?:\s*\p{L}){3}[\p{L}\s]*$/u` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6oIm1/1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if there are any three letters *anywhere* inside a string using

```js
const regex = /(?:\P{L}*\p{L}){3}/u;
```

If you only want to allow whitespaces and letters, you will need to precise the pattern to

```js
const regex = /^(?:\s*\p{L}){3}[\p{L}\s]*$/u;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6oIm1/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\s*\p{L}){3}` - three occurrences of zero or more whitespaces followed with a letter
- `[\p{L}\s]*` - zero or more letters or whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: its works fine, but one thing, eslint showing that it is Unsafe regular expression(security/detect-unsafe-regex)

Comment: @ViktorAczq It is safe, do not believe the warning.

Comment: @ViktorAczq It is all due to nested quantifiers. `/\p{L}\P{L}*\p{L}\P{L}*\p{L}/u` will then be the fix.

Comment: Yes, unwrapping the group will fix the problem, but it will make the regex longer and less customizable, but alas, that is Sonar and their regex developers did not do their job well.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:
`/(\p{L}.*?){3}/u`
As there could be other characters in between the letters(of any language), we can use the . to match all characters. The *? allows us to keep matching until we find another \p character